# Managed Identity - how to debug locally

Tags: c#, azure-managed-identity

I am using the following code to test system managed identity on my web app and it works fine when I deploy in Azure but is there a way to test locally(without giving permissions to my Azure account for the resource?)?

```
AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync("https://EASDemo.vault.azure.net/secrets/test")
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
return new string[] { secret.Value };
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Options to test locally (VS, CLI) are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#local-development-authentication):

> ### Authenticating with Visual Studio
>
> To authenticate by using Visual Studio:
>
> 1. Sign in to Visual Studio and use Tools > Options to open Options.
> 2. Select Azure Service Authentication, choose an account for local development, and select OK.
>
> If you run into problems using Visual Studio, such as errors that
> involve the token provider file, carefully review the preceding steps.
>
> You may need to reauthenticate your developer token. To do so, select
> Tools > Options, and then select Azure Service Authentication. Look
> for a Re-authenticate link under the selected account. Select it to
> authenticate.

If you do not want to use your developer identity, you can also use a certificate or secret key (though not recommended as it can be checked in to source repository by mistake). These options are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  Currently, we are using a Certificate based approach to authenticate Key Vault. Our most of the services are deployed on Service Fabric (and few in app service) and all the developers do not have developer identity(we have 100+ resources working on project).  how should we handle local debugging scenario? Developers mostly prefer to check-in code after debugging in local.

Comment: Also the documentation says "Ideally, the credentials never appear on developer workstations and aren't checked into source control. " but if we follow multiple approaches to allow local debugging then the above point is not correct.

Comment: Please check this answer on how to use cert based approach for service fabric. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859477/access-key-vault-from-local-service-fabric-cluster-with-msi. Please let me know if you have follow-up questions.

Comment: On occasion I have found it necessary to logout and login again (remove account from VS and add it back) - even though the credentials were up to date and working for other tasks in VS